# Broadcast Receiver in Library Not working

Tags: android

Hi Guys I created a broadcast receiver in a Library Project.

below is the code

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // When our Alaram time is triggered , this method will be excuted (onReceive)
     // We're invoking a service in this method which shows Notification to the User
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmNotificationService.class);
      context.startService(myIntent);
    }

}
```

I trigger the broadcast receiver using alarm manager using the below code.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("Alarm");
        myIntent.setClass(activity, AlarmReceiver.class);    
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, myIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000;
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time , pendingIntent);
```

I defined the receiver in the main project's manifest as shown below

```
<receiver android:name="com.library.packagename.AlarmReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="Alarm" />             
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but the broadcast receiver is not getting triggered.

Comment: Did you try defining the receiver in library itself?

Comment: Did you try the solution I gave ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this without setting the action, your broadcast will fire.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent, 0);
```

Also remove `<action android:name="Alarm" />` from the manifest.

Comment: I am not sure whether this made it work. But u r right,Action is not required .

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your Library Brodacstreceiver to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Make sure of it and if you haven't registered your receiver in your Library AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<receiver name="libprojectpackagename.AlarmReceiver">
  ...
</receiver>
```

that's it ...